# Creating an excel file with EPPlus, but it is always read-only

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

I'm creating/sending a file with EPPlus like this:

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
{

    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet");
    ... //create file here

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/xlsx";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + ".xlsx");
    Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray());
    Response.End();
}
```

Everything works fine, except the file always comes back as read-only, and I can't figure out why.  Within the "package" object, there is a file object with a IsReadOnly field, but the file object is null.  I anticipate that I'm not creating the xcel file correctly, but this is the only way I could figure out how to create the file well.  Initially I was using a memory stream, but doing that, I ran into issues when the excel file was bigger than 50 rows.

Edit/update: So I initiate the code block by clicking a button "Download as Excel File".  The code runs, creating the file, and the user is prompted with a "You have chose to open: thisismyexcelfile.xlsx which is a: XLSX file (size here) from: mywebsite.  What should firefox do with this file?"  After selecting "Open with OpenOffice Calc" the spreedsheet opens and displays appropriately but is read-only.

Edit/update: I checked the file properties with OpenOffice.  Under Properties/Security there is a "Open file Read Only" checkbox, but it is already unchecked and disabled.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the file "comes back as read-only"? Could you describe the scenario more precisely?

Comment: Question updated to be more explicit.

Comment: Are you sure it's not MS Office doing that? That's the default for any files downloaded off the net. It makes them readonly and gives a security warning.

Comment: I don't actually have MS Office, but I did consider that it was OpenOffice doing it.  Is there a way I can prevent that or do I just have to assume the user knows how to work around this?

Comment: Actually I think it's the browser that makes the file read-only when you choose to open it directly. If you save it somewhere explicitly, it doesn't happen. So in any case, the issue is not in your code.

Comment: Wow.  Well now I just feel silly.  Thank you, wish I could accept your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, I was able to verify that saving the file to a location on the disk and opening it directly did not open the file as read-only, implying the problem was not with the code, but the browsers handling of files downloaded from the internet.

Answer (score 6):

I found this example, I see 3 main differences

1. **Response.ContentType** is set to **application/vnd.openxmlformats**
2. **Response.WriteFile** is used instead or **Response.BinaryWrite**
3. In this example the file is being saved to the server, sent as response and then deleted

   ```
   void ExportToExcel(Event evt)
   {
       var fileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.GetTempPath() + "\\" +  
                               DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".xlsx");

       using (var xls = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
       {
           var sheet = xls.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(evt.Title);

           sheet.Cell(1, 1).Value = "First name";
           sheet.Cell(1, 2).Value = "Last name";
           sheet.Cell(1, 3).Value = "E-mail";
           sheet.Cell(1, 4).Value = "Phone";
           sheet.Cell(1, 5).Value = "Registered";
           sheet.Cell(1, 6).Value = "Live Meeting";

           var i = 1;
           foreach(var attendee in evt.Attendees)
           {
               i++;

               var profile = attendee.Profile;
               sheet.Cell(i, 1).Value = profile.FirstName;
               sheet.Cell(i, 2).Value = profile.LastName;
               sheet.Cell(i, 3).Value = profile.Email;
              sheet.Cell(i, 4).Value = profile.Phone;
               sheet.Cell(i, 5).Value = att.Created.ToString();
               sheet.Cell(i, 6).Value = att.LiveMeeting.ToString();
           }

           xls.Save(); 
       }

       Response.Clear();
       Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats";
       Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                      "attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
       Response.WriteFile(fileInfo.FullName);
       Response.Flush();

       if (fileInfo.Exists)
           fileInfo.Delete(); 
   }
   ```

Comment: taken from http://gunnarpeipman.com/2010/05/using-excelpackage-to-create-excel-sheets-on-server/