# How to save an excel file in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating an MVC controller action where JSON data passed in to the method is to be written to an excel file. Right now, I'm testing out the functionality by using hardcoded data from a data table based on the example from [this blog post](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/bd6c67/how-to-create-excel-file-using-C-Sharp/).

Here is the code I have:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ExportData()
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook worKbooK;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worKsheeT;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range celLrangE;

                try
                {
                    excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    excel.Visible = false;
                    excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
                    worKbooK = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);


                    worKsheeT = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)worKbooK.ActiveSheet;
                    worKsheeT.Name = "StudentRepoertCard";

                    worKsheeT.Range[worKsheeT.Cells[1, 1], worKsheeT.Cells[1, 8]].Merge();
                    worKsheeT.Cells[1, 1] = "Student Report Card";
                    worKsheeT.Cells.Font.Size = 15;


                    int rowcount = 2;

                    foreach (DataRow datarow in ExportToExcel().Rows)
                    {
                        rowcount += 1;
                        for (int i = 1; i <= ExportToExcel().Columns.Count; i++)
                        {

                            if (rowcount == 3)
                            {
                                worKsheeT.Cells[2, i] = ExportToExcel().Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                                worKsheeT.Cells.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

                            }

                            worKsheeT.Cells[rowcount, i] = datarow[i - 1].ToString();

                            if (rowcount > 3)
                            {
                                if (i == ExportToExcel().Columns.Count)
                                {
                                    if (rowcount % 2 == 0)
                                    {
                                        celLrangE = worKsheeT.Range[worKsheeT.Cells[rowcount, 1], worKsheeT.Cells[rowcount, ExportToExcel().Columns.Count]];
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }

                    celLrangE = worKsheeT.Range[worKsheeT.Cells[1, 1], worKsheeT.Cells[rowcount, ExportToExcel().Columns.Count]];
                    celLrangE.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Borders border = celLrangE.Borders;
                    border.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                    border.Weight = 2d;

                    celLrangE = worKsheeT.Range[worKsheeT.Cells[1, 1], worKsheeT.Cells[2, ExportToExcel().Columns.Count]];

                    worKbooK.SaveAs("\\root\\test.xlsx"); 
                    worKbooK.Close();
                    excel.Quit();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return Json(new { saveSuccess = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

                }
                finally
                {
                    worKsheeT = null;
                    celLrangE = null;
                    worKbooK = null;

                }

                return Json(new { saveSuccess = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            //private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            //{
            //    dataGridView1.DataSource = ExportToExcel();
            //}
            public System.Data.DataTable ExportToExcel()  
            {  
                System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();  
                table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));  
                table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));  
                table.Columns.Add("Sex", typeof(string));  
                table.Columns.Add("Subject1", typeof(int));  
                table.Columns.Add("Subject2", typeof(int));  
                table.Columns.Add("Subject3", typeof(int));  
                table.Columns.Add("Subject4", typeof(int));  
                table.Columns.Add("Subject5", typeof(int));  
                table.Columns.Add("Subject6", typeof(int));  
                table.Rows.Add(1, "Amar", "M", 78, 59, 72, 95, 83, 77);  
                table.Rows.Add(2, "Mohit", "M", 76, 65, 85, 87, 72, 90);  
                table.Rows.Add(3, "Garima", "F", 77, 73, 83, 64, 86, 63);  
                table.Rows.Add(4, "jyoti", "F", 55, 77, 85, 69, 70, 86);  
                table.Rows.Add(5, "Avinash", "M", 87, 73, 69, 75, 67, 81);  
                table.Rows.Add(6, "Devesh", "M", 92, 87, 78, 73, 75, 72);  
                return table;  
            }
```

Right now, the code works up until the point where the save happens. For some reason, the file location is not found. I was assuming that the name of the file had to be listed at the end of the path after the containing folder in order to provide the name, but maybe this isn't the correct way to specify the file path.

What I actually need to do is to allow the user to choose the file location in file explorer, provide a name, and then save the file. Since this is the case, the file path would have to be provided dynamically. I've looked at many SO posts and articles but I haven't seen a clear example of how to do this.

**How should the code be modified for the user to be able to specify the file name and path?**

Comment: allow the user to choose location to save the file where? in a folder of the server? not sure if I'm understading

Comment: @derloopkat on their local machine. They essentially need to be able to download the excel file.

Comment: I am not an MVC person but have had bad experiences with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. Make sure you don't have EXCEL.exe processes after your program runs. If interested in a better approach to building Xml files I would use OpenXml. This [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_jones/2010/06/22/writing-large-excel-files-with-the-open-xml-sdk/) "SAX" section is a good tutorial.

Comment: @loremIpsum1771, ahh, your C# code runs at server. If you save the file with this `worKbooK.SaveAs(...)`, it's going to be saved at server. What you need is putting the file in the response. User makes a request and server returns a file (instead of Json). Then user will be able to choose where to save it. This functionality is provided by Internet browser. All you have to do is adding the file **as attachment** in the response with correct Mime type.

Comment: @PhilipBrack I need to export to Excel not xml.

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 Excel is an xml format and that library is a tool to build the xlsx files.

Comment: please check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510313/c-sharp-asp-net-mvc-downloading-excel-file-using-filestreamresult You need something similar. Another option is saving the file at server first, and then return the file in the response. But the above it's more straight forward and don't need to deal with temporary file deletion.

Comment: @PhilipBrack Oh ok. I was trying to do this with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel though

Comment: @derloopkat it looks like the person from the post was having issues with the file being read-only

Comment: You should not use Office Interop in a server context. It's unstable, hard to debug, probably not licensed to do that, and [Microsoft says don't do it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office). You should use a tool that can generate Excel files in managed code, such as EPPlus, NPOI, ClosedXML, Open XML SDK, Aspose, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot choose to save the file from their browser. You need to serve up the file and let them download it and save it where they like.

Also, the server you want a production ASP.NET application deployed to *probably* doesn't have a copy of Excel installed (and even if it does interop gets a little messy IMHO) so you probably want to use a openXml library such as EPPlus instead.

This would let you do something like this:

```
public IActionResult ExportData()
{
    using (var excel = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        var wks = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("StudentReportCard");
        wks.Cells[1,1].LoadFromCollection(GetStudentRecords(), PrintHeaders:true);
        return File(excel.GetAsByteArray(),"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "export.xlsx");
    };
}
private static IEnumerable<StudentRecord> GetStudentRecords()
{
    yield return new StudentRecord
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "John",
        Subject = "Maths",
        Score = 77.9
    };
    yield return new StudentRecord
    {
        Id = 2,
        Name = "Jane",
        Subject = "Maths",
        Score = 78.9
    };
    yield return new StudentRecord
    {
        Id = 3,
        Name = "Jo",
        Subject = "Maths",
        Score = 99.9
    };
}
```

Which sends a file like this named 'export.xlsx' for the user to save from their browser:

[image]

Comment: Is this a nuget package, I'm only seeing update versions on github. If it's not on nuget anymore, is there any other library that could do this that you would recommend?

Comment: yes, its a nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/ (or, an unofficial port if you are using aspnet core: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus.core/)